# python: Applying t-test to every column in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, t-test

I have a dataframe that has about 100,000 columns. The first column of the dataframe is 'labels'. The data of every column is divided into two groups. One is label==1, and other one is label ==0. Just like above:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a65GK.png)

My goal is applying t-test to every column according to the different 'labels'. The following is my codes:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats as ss

def t_test(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    column_list = [x for x in df.columns if x != 'labels']
    t_test_results = {}
    for column in column_list:
    non_essential = df.where('labels'==1).dropna()[column]
    essential = df.where('labels'==0).dropna()[column]
    t_test_results[column] = ss.ttest_rel(non_essential, essential)
    result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(t_test_results, orient='Index')
    result_df.columns = ['statistic', 'pvalue']
    return result_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = t_test('encoding_test_data.csv')
    with open('t_test_result.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(result))
```

'encoding_test_data.csv' is my test file. And I got the error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/master_subject/t_test.py", line 22, in <module>
result = t_test('encoding_test_data.csv')
File "E:/master_subject/t_test.py", line 14, in t_test
non_essential = df.where('labels'==1).dropna()[column]
File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7772, in where
errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast)
File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7516, in _where
raise ValueError('Array conditional must be same shape as '
ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

How can I get my goal?